# How to call closest() on first element selected by querySelectorAll in custom chainable JavaScript library?

Tags: javascript, closest, selectors-api

What exactly is wrong about my try to call `closest()` on first element selected by `querySelectorAll` in my custom JavaScript library?

```js
var $ = function(selector){

  var x; 
  var obj = {
  
    myLib(selector){
      return x || document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    },
    
    cl(selector){
      x[0].closest(selector);
      return this;
    },
      
    style(aaa,bbb){
           !aaa && !bbb ? x.getAttribute('style')                         :
            aaa &&  bbb ? x.forEach( zzz => { zzz.style[aaa]=bbb;     } ) :
      aaa.includes(';') ? x.forEach( zzz => { zzz.style.cssText+=aaa; } )
                        : getComputedStyle(x,null)[aaa];
      return this;
    },
      
  };
        
  x = obj.myLib(selector);
  return obj;
  
};

// now i want to call it

$('div').style('background','#FFFF00');
$('.kilo').cl('.uniform').style('color:','#880088');
```

```html
<div id="foxtrott">
  foxtrott
  <div class="uniform">
    uniform
    <div class="charlie">
      charlie
      <div class="kilo">
        kilo
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I change my cl() function to this the console tells me: `$(...).cl(...) is null`

```
cl(selector){
  return x[0].closest(selector);
},
```

I really don't get it how to do it correctly. :(

Comment: You’re not doing anything with `x[0].closest(selector)`. In the `style` function, you’re also not doing anything with `x.getAttribute('style')` and `getComputedStyle(x,null)[aaa]`.

Comment: When I try to `return x[0].closest(selector)` then console tells me it's null

Comment: Did you probably mean `x = x[0].closest(selector)`? Change the current state of what is selected and *then* `return this` to continue the fluent interface?

Comment: `$('.kilo')` - Are you trying to change font forecolor div ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting `x` in `cl`.

i.e.

```
    cl(selector) {
      x = [x[0].closest(selector)];
      return this;
    },
```

Also of note, you'll want to drop the trailing colon on `'border-left:'` (EDIT: or `'color:'` in your latest edition)

Here's a "working" example
https://repl.it/repls/MixedRipeGlobalarrays

Comment: thanks! this works. :)

but i don't understand why i would have to set `x`  because i never did in my other functions OR NO, WAIT i think i got it :D this makes sense. thanks again!!